# MySQL trigger on same table on update

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a startlists table with order numbers. Per test_of_event_id (found in a related table called subscriptions) there is a sequence like (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...) creating a nice list.

I want to make this list easy maintainable (with phpmyadmin) when list numbers change. 
I made a trigger for table startlists on update

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `edit_startlists` BEFORE UPDATE ON `startlists`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.order_number != OLD.order_number) THEN
    IF (NEW.subscription_id!=OLD.subscription_id) THEN
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    ELSE
        IF (NEW.order_number < OLD.order_number) THEN
            /*number has become smaller --> everthing equal to or bigger then new , and smaller then old --> +1 */
            UPDATE startlists
            JOIN subscriptions 
            ON subscriptions.id = startlists.subscription_id
            SET order_number = (order_number+1)

            WHERE order_number >= NEW.order_number 
            AND order_number < OLD.order_number
            AND subscriptions.test_of_event_id=(SELECT sub.test_of_event_id FROM subscriptions sub WHERE sub.id=OLD.subscription_id);

        ELSE
            /*number has become bigger --> everthing equal to or smaller then new , and bigger then old --> -1 */
            UPDATE startlists
            JOIN subscriptions 
            ON subscriptions.id = startlists.subscription_id
            SET order_number = (order_number-1)

            WHERE order_number <= NEW.order_number 
            AND order_number > OLD.order_number
            AND subscriptions.test_of_event_id=(SELECT sub.test_of_event_id FROM subscriptions sub WHERE sub.id=OLD.subscription_id);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;

END
```

There was no problem in creating the trigger, only when an order number has changed I get this error.

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'startlists' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I'm using InnoDB, isn't this supposed to lock only one row?

I came up with something else: 
I added a boolean field (procedure_check) to table startlists to check to avoid recursion. Then made a trigger that calls the procedure if necessary:

```
   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS edit_startlist;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER edit_startlist AFTER UPDATE ON startlists
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE current_test_of_event_id INT;
    DECLARE max_order_number INT;
    IF (NEW.order_number != OLD.order_number)
    THEN
      IF (NEW.procedure_edit = 0)
      THEN
        IF (NEW.subscription_id != OLD.subscription_id)
        THEN
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
        ELSE
          SET current_test_of_event_id = (SELECT test_of_event_id
                                          FROM (SELECT sub.test_of_event_id
                                                FROM subscriptions sub
                                                WHERE sub.id = OLD.subscription_id
                                               ) AS current_subscription
          );

          SET max_order_number = (SELECT MAX(s.order_number)
                                  FROM startlists s, subscriptions sub
                                  WHERE s.subscription_id = sub.id
                                        AND sub.test_of_event_id = current_test_of_event_id
          );
          IF (NEW.order_number <= 0 OR NEW.order_number > max_order_number)
          THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
          ELSE
            CALL adjust_startlist(NEW.order_number,OLD.order_number,current_test_of_event_id);
          END IF;
        END IF;
      ELSE
        /*this edit is made by procedure, change the procedure boolean back to 0, so it is ready for a next manual edit*/
        UPDATE startlists SET
          procedure_edit=0 WHERE
          id=NEW.id;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And the procedure:

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE adjust_startlist
  (IN new_order_number INT UNSIGNED, IN old_order_number INT UNSIGNED, IN current_test_of_event_id INT UNSIGNED)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    IF (new_order_number < old_order_number)
    THEN
    /*number has become smaller --> everthing equal to or bigger then new , and smaller then old --> +1 */

      UPDATE startlists
        JOIN subscriptions
          ON subscriptions.id = startlists.subscription_id
      SET order_number  = (order_number + 1),
        procedure_check = 1

      WHERE order_number >= new_order_number
            AND order_number < old_order_number
            AND subscriptions.test_of_event_id = current_test_of_event_id;
        /* UPDATE startlists SET order_number = NEW.*/

    ELSE
    /*number has become bigger --> everthing equal to or smaller then new , and bigger then old --> -1 */
      UPDATE startlists
        JOIN subscriptions
          ON subscriptions.id = startlists.subscription_id
      SET order_number  = (order_number - 1),
        procedure_check = 1

      WHERE order_number <= new_order_number
            AND order_number > old_order_number
            AND subscriptions.test_of_event_id = current_test_of_event_id;
    END IF;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I execute, procedure and trigger get added, no syntax error. 
But when I try to modify an order number I get this error:

```
#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

I have no idea what is causing this error, let alone how to solve. I've researched it but all examples I came across don't apply to this.

Comment: in most DBMS, including MySQL, you cannot update a table in a trigger for the same table, as the error mentions; this is to avoid infinite recursion (your trigger makes an update, which executes your trigger again and so on). You need to come up with different logic, or use a stored procedure

Comment: I see, indeed it can cause recursion. However I really need an easy way, since there will be persons maintaining the database with not that much IT knowlegde. How can I make a stored procedure easy to use in phpmyadmin? Or are there other options?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot use the table being updated in the same query.  You can include the table multiple times in the `from` clause but you are not doing this.  But, there is an exception if you nest the queries enough.

Try changing this line:

```
subscriptions.test_of_event_id = (SELECT sub.test_of_event_id
                                  FROM subscriptions sub
                                  WHERE sub.id=OLD.subscription_id
                                 )
```

to:

```
subscriptions.test_of_event_id = (SELECT test_of_event_id
                                  FROM (SELECT sub.test_of_event_id
                                        FROM subscriptions sub
                                        WHERE sub.id=OLD.subscription_id
                                       ) s
                                 )
```

MySQL actually materializes the subquery, which makes this allowed.

Comment: Tested it, and doesn't work. I guess the problem is with the update rather then the select as okaram suggested?

Comment: Maybe missing an alias